# Dynamic Web Service URL with MonoTouch

Tags: web-services, xamarin.ios

I have an app written using MonoTouch that relies on a Web Services URL backend.  I need the ability to set the URL of this backend dynamically at run time from within the app (or from within it's settings).

I've read this article on CodeProject that describes setting URL dynamically:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic#_rating

But I can't find this option in MonoDevelop.

I've tried altering the Url property of my service, but it appears there is more to it than that.  (Specifically the "references.cs" file added by the web service seems to also have the URL hard coded in various attributes).

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

--scotru

Comment: P.S.  I'm using .NET 2.0 style web services.

Answer (score 1):

When Mono generates C# wrapper for SOAP web-service to you, it creates 2 constructors of wrapper. Second one contains URL parameter, which you can use to set proper URL and so switch between web-services.

Example from project, which is in production (file Reference.cs):

```cs
public partial class ServicesInfoImplService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
...
        public ServicesInfoImplService() {
            this.Url = "<DEFAULT_URL>";
        }

        public ServicesInfoImplService(string url) {
            this.Url = url;
        }
...
```

Comment: Yes, but when I change the URL here, the attribute decorators still get the full URL path to the old URL so the service doesn't work right.  It's the generated attributes that are giving me trouble.

Comment: I rechecked code. If you pass new url, service wrapper should work with it.
No matter that references to old url are hardcoded (in reference.map and *.wsdl files).

Here's example of constructor: 
if (AppSettings.DEBUG_SERVICE_MODE)
    client = new Service(AppSettings.DEBUG_URL);
else {
    client = new Service();